# HLS Client using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am a beginner to FFMPEG. Currently building a client application for HLS (Http Live Streaming) using FFMPEG. For this I find some useful functions in /libavformat/hlsproto.c and other hls related files. But not sure what are the APIs which are for clients use and how to access them for a simple HLS client. Any small examples or documents will help a lot for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at ffplay.c (or avplay.c in the libav project) to see an example player.

Comment: Thanks. As I understand from FFMPEG framework, to integrate HLS, need not call any specific APIs particular to HLS from client. FFMPEG infers the proper protocol and corresponding APIs based on file/URL format provided in avformat_open_input() function. Hence, client should follow the same principles as in ffplay.